# Saving Jsonified Java Objects in Firestore

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to go about taking a POJO class, writing it into a JSON string and saving it to Firestore?

I know it is possible to save POJO classes to Firestore, however, a lot of my classes have annotations such as JsonIgnore, JsonProperty etc.

For example I could have the following class

```
@Data
public class Player {

  @JsonIgnore
  private String id;

  @JsonProperty("playersName")
  private String name;

  @JsonPropety("playersAge")
  private String age;

}
```

If I save this POJO directly into Firestore, I will get the following

```
id: "12345"
name: "John Doe"
age: "30"
```

If I convert it to JSON string it will look along something like this, which I would like to save into Firestore

```
{
 "playersName": "John Doe"
 "playersAge": "30"
}
```

In Firestore I would like to save it as the above JSON string

```
playersName: "John Doe"
playersAge: "30"
```

However, Firestore doesn't allow to save primitives/arrays, so what would be the best approach to wanting to accomplish the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firestore has its own annotations for ignoring POJO members or changing their names.  Look into [@Exclude](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Exclude) as an equivalent to @JsonIgnore.  Also see annotations [@PropertyName](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/PropertyName), [@IgnoreExtraProperties](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/IgnoreExtraProperties), and [@ThrowOnExtraProperties](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/ThrowOnExtraProperties).

(Note that I linked to the Android API annotations.  If you're using the Java server SDK, they will exist in a different package, e.g. [@Exclude](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-firestore/latest/com/google/cloud/firestore/annotation/Exclude.html).)

If you don't use these annotations, you will instead have to manually copy the fields you want to save into the document using a `Map<String, Object>` and provide that to `set()` or `update()`.  Similar when reading the documents - you will be provided with a Map to copy fields out of.

Comment: Lombok and `@Exclude` Interaction: You're using Lombok's `@Data` annotation, which automatically generates getters and setters. The Firestore SDK may be using the getter to serialize the field, ignoring the `@Exclude` annotation on the field itself. To fix this, try placing the `@Exclude` annotation on the getter method for the field. Lombok allows you to manually define a getter and annotate it.